# Returning string value from sproc is not populating c# datatable

Tags: c#, string, validation, stored-procedures

I have a sproc that is returning a message when a validation fails before saving data.  The return message is a combo of string and date.  IE 'The dates that you have selected are outside of the plan span 01/01/2017 - 12/31/2017'

It is going into a class where the message is type string.  When it returns back, it is somehow just emptying out.

```
        private ErrorInfo SystemValidation(string Validationstr) {

            DataTable dt = ServerCore.LogicalData.Retrieve(IncedoPatientQueries.ImcSystemValidationProcedureHandler,
                                         new QueryParam("data", Validationstr),
                                         new QueryParam("splitString", "@|"));

            string msg = string.Empty;

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                msg = dt.Rows[0][0].GetStringorEmpty(StringOptions.Trimmed);

            if (msg != "OK") {
                msg = dt.Rows[0]["Message"].GetStringorEmpty(StringOptions.Trimmed);
                return new ErrorInfo() { ErrorState = ErrorStates.Warning, ErrorMessage = msg };
            } else
                return new ErrorInfo() { ErrorState = ErrorStates.Success, ErrorMessage = string.Empty };
        }

    public class ErrorInfo {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public ErrorStates ErrorState { get; set; }
    }
```

When I look at dt.Rows[0]["Message"], i get nothing.  If i pass back just a plain string, it populates just fine.

I think it might have something to do with the StringOptions.Trimmed but Im not sure.

```
DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @SplitString NVARCHAR(5)
SET @Data = 'SprocList=imc_PatientInsurance_CheckSpanValidation@|Insuspan_I=0@|Insu_Id=25745@|Plan_Id=8282@|Grp_Id=0@|Patient_ID=1222@|DateFrom=10/10/2019@|DateTo=01/02/2020'
SET @SplitString = '@|'
exec [dbo].[imc_System_ValidationProcedureHandler] @Data, @SplitString

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[imc_System_ValidationProcedureHandler] (
    @Data VARCHAR(MAX),
    @SplitString NVARCHAR(5)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SprocCount INT
    DECLARE @LoopCount INT
    DECLARE @ResultMessage VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @SprocName VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @NVPList VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @SprocTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), SprocName VARCHAR(100))
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)

    CREATE TABLE #Result (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Message VARCHAR(5000))

    SET @NVPList = dbo.GetValueFromNVPList('SprocList', @Data, @SplitString)

    INSERT INTO @SprocTable (SprocName)
        SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@NVPList, ',')

    SET @SprocCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @LoopCount = 1

    WHILE @LoopCount <= @SprocCount
        BEGIN
            SELECT @SprocName = SprocName FROM @SprocTable WHERE ID = @LoopCount
            SET @Sql = 'EXECUTE ' + @SprocName + '''' + REPLACE(@Data, '''', '''''') + ''', ''' + @SplitString + ''''

            INSERT INTO #Result
                EXECUTE (@Sql)

            SELECT @ResultMessage = Message FROM #Result WHERE ID = @LoopCount


            IF SUBSTRING(@ResultMessage,1,2) = 'Ok'
                BEGIN
                    IF LEN(@ResultMessage) = 2
                        DELETE #Result WHERE ID = @LoopCount
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    DELETE #Result WHERE ID <> @LoopCount
                    BREAK
                END

            SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
        END

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Result) = 0
            SELECT 'OK' as Message
        ELSE
            SELECT Message FROM #Result ORDER BY ID
END
```

Comment: What is the SQL code you are using? Are you sure your error message is in a column called "Message"?

Comment: Yes, verified that Message is in the result set.  Its only that field.  It returns 'OK' or an error message when validation fails.  Added sql code to the post

Comment: When the message is a plain string, it populates dt.Rows[0]["Message"] just fine.  If it contains anything else, like the date span I want to see, it is empty.

Comment: You should probably post the code for `imc_System_ValidationProcedureHandler` then. It sounds like the problem is in there somewhere.

Comment: sproc added to post